# CSS Flip: Links not working in Chrome (webkit)

Tags: css, debugging, animation, cross-browser, core-animation

I'm trying to create a simple CSS Flip effect on some images and put links on the backside... however, the links work in FireFox, but not Chrome or Safari.

I've tried many different methods, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
/* Artists Flip */

.rsp-img-center {
margin: 0 auto;
}

.front img {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
background-color: #000;
}

#f1_container {
position: relative;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 200px;
height: 175px;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-moz-perspective: 1000;
-o-perspective: 1000;
perspective: 1000;
}

#f1_card {
width: 200px;
height: 175px;
position: relative;
transition: 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transition: 0.6s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transition: 0.6s;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
position: relative;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
z-index: 100;
clear: both;
top: 0;
 }

.face {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.face.back {
display: inline-block;
z-index: 500;
position: absolute;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
background-image: url("http://beta2.thrivemusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/flip_back.png");
background-attachment:local;
position: relative;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;

 }


 .face.back a{
z-index:     9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;

 }

.front {
background-color: #000000;
 }

.back {
background-attachment:local;
background-position:center; 
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Here's the codepen URL: http://codepen.io/samkimdesign/pen/tAvDn

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Oh wait I may have figured it out...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, have a look at [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cinarchesi/d156e8rj/)

css3 and html :

```css
#card {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    -o-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}   
.back, .front {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;    
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease-in;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;    
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);  
    background: #bde;
    overflow: hidden;
}   
.front {
    background: #fde;
}
#card-container {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
}   
#card-container:target .back {   
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
#card-container:target .front {      
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="card-container">
    <div id="card">
        <div class="back">This is the back of the card
        <br/><a href="#front">Go to front</a>
        </div>
        <div class="front">This is the front of the card
        <br/><a href="#card-container">Go to back</a>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is excellent solution . i am able to do it on Chrome and IE ( 10+ ) both .